# Copying a label followed by input field contents

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, copy-paste

Given:
A label Text followed by an input field similar to a form (e.g. Name: ________ (input box) )

Requirement:
Need to develop a mechanism to be able to copy both text and input field in a single go
i.e. highlighting/selecting the entire line of text and input box.

Problem:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> only copies the text only and not the entire data along with input box.

Reason for such a requirement:
I have a form in which Label is the domain of a website and input box is for author profile id
(e.g. [www.facebook.com/_______](http://www.facebook.com/_______)_ (input box) )

Behaviour intended:
When User selects the entire [www.facebook.com/](http://www.facebook.com/) and the author id ( say john007) thinking he will paste "www.facebook.com/john007" somewhere.

Technicality:
My clipboard should copy both the text and the input box contents.

Implementation:
Was thinking of playing with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> events but cannot figure out the exact behaviour required.

```
<div>
           <label>www.facebook.com/</label>
           <input  style="width:150px" type="Text" id="nameInput"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an appropriate usecase for the [`<label>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-label-element.html#the-label-element). I'd expect something like

```
<div>
    <label for="nameInput">Facebook page:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" value="www.facebook.com/">
</div>
```

Then one can input and select the full address. And you could add some script that eventually prefixes the string onkeyup and -paste.

Or you do something like that:

```
<div>
    <label for="nameInput">Your profile id:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameInput">
    (<label for="url">URL:</label>
    <output id="url">www.facebook.com/</output>)
</div>
```

When the input changes, you'd snip the prefix from pasted urls in the input field, and change the text of the output field appropriately, from where the user could select and copy.

```
// on ready
$("#nameInput").on("keyup paste input change", function(e) {
    var name = this.value.replace(/^(https?://www.facebook.com/)/, "");
    this.value = name;
    $("#url").text("www.facebook.com/"+name);
});
```

Comment: 1.Placeholder or the watermark in my case is "profile id" since I am any ways giving the entire domain before

2.output tag works for HTML 5 and I am not keen towards it .

Comment: Yes, that's true, placeholder is not really what I meant. Better to start with the value right away...

Comment: does the code snippet at the bottom copy the entire URL(text + i/p box) to the clipboard ??

Comment: No, JavaScript has no (easy) access to the clipboard. Search Stackoverflow on that, there are many questions. The snippet just updates the text in the output element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Ctrl+C functionality you can use below code(But it works on IE):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" wrap="hard" onblur="CopyToClipboard(this)"></textarea>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">
function CopyToClipboard(text) {
    Copied = text.createTextRange();
    Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}test
</script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps... Cheers!!!